# Heroku.yml building all service images but the containers cannot communicate via http client

Tags: asp.net, docker, heroku

It works with docker compose on my local machine, using the service name as as the hostname for the httpclient call but it doesn't work on heroku and I keep getting the following error, apparently there's a problem with the multi-container communication

```
 Connection id "0HM9TMTBOMRA8", Request id "0HM9TMTBOMRA8:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
2021-07-03T00:14:03.379601+00:00 app[web.1]: at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-07-03T00:14:03.379601+00:00 app[web.1]: at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
ancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-07-03T00:14:03.379602+00:00 app[web.1]: at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-07-03T00:14:03.379603+00:00 app[web.1]: at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

This is my heroku.yml file

```
build:
  docker:
    web: DockerComposeTest.RabbitMqConsumer/Dockerfile
    api: DockerComposeTest.RabbitMqListener/Dockerfile
```

and this is my endpoint which I call via swagger.

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTestEndpoint()
        {
            using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                // Call *mywebapi*, and display its response in the page
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri("http://DockerComposeTest.RabbitMqPublisher:80/WeatherForecast") // ASP.NET 3 (VS 2019 only)
                };
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
               return Ok(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
        }
```

And I commented out app.UseHttpsRedirection() in my start-up.cs.

For some reason heroku doesn't support docker-compose.yml so I'm stuck with this as much as I know.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each image is deployed in a Dyno and [networking of Dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime) is not supported. In this case your apps (cointainers) can communicate over HTTPS using the assigned Heroky URL (ie app.herokuapp.com).

Comment: Thank you, but there are two asp.net web apps and only one is exposed with the heroku app url. Or is this not possible with heroku? And how else can I deploy a microservice project that will have multi container communication?

Comment: Multi container communication is not supported, each web app or service is deployed on its own Dyno. You can deploy both apps on its own Dyno and access them via the herokuapp.com URL